# Port number disappearing in URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have web app that was running fine on my local server the other day, behaving as it should but now something weird is happening and as far as i'm aware i haven't made any changes. When i choose to run the app on the local server the page will display fine. But when i click on a button, it's supposed to essentially send some data back and refresh the page with new information, which is what was happening before. Now however it is redirecting me to http://localhost/FirstSpringMVCProject/ instead of http://localhost:8080/FirstSpringMVCProject/ and i am getting an error. How to fix this? Below is the relevant code..

Controller

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView display() {     

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("DisplayMatchup");
        model.addObject("matchup", new Matchup());

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute("team") String s) {
        Util.updateParse(s);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("DisplayMatchup");
        model.addObject("matchup", new Matchup());

        return model;
    }
}
```

Spring servlet dispatcher

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


  <context:component-scan base-package="com.gontuseries.hellocontroller" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>

  <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
 </bean>


</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>Web projects</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>DisplayMatchup.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

View (DisplayMatchup.jsp)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<style>
ol {
    padding: 12px;
    background-color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
body {
    font-family: Courier;
    text-align: center;
}
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Courier;
    white-space: normal;
}
</style>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Basketball Player Rater</title>
</head>
<h2>Basketball Player Rater</h2>
<body>
<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://results.cae10gzzpyrn.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/results"
     user="user"  password="pass"/>
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY wins DESC;
</sql:query>
<ol>
<h2>Team 1</h2>
<form:form method="post" action="http://localhost/FirstSpringMVCProject/" modelAttribute="team">
<button type="submit" name="team" value="${matchup.teams[0]}${matchup.teams[1]}"/>${matchup.teams[0]}</button>
</form:form>
</ol>
<ol>
<h2>Team 2</h2>
<form:form method="post" action="http://localhost/FirstSpringMVCProject/" modelAttribute="team">
<button type="submit" name="team" value="${matchup.teams[1]}${matchup.teams[0]}"/>${matchup.teams[1]}</button>
</form:form>
</ol>
<h3>Results:</h3>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<c:out value="${row.player}"/> --- <c:out value="${row.winrate}"/>
</br>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks, also if there is a better way to do what i'm trying to do then i'm open to suggestion.

Comment: Can you post your html and javascript?

Comment: added the view, there's no JS

Comment: REMOVE YOUR CREDENTIALS

Comment: @BenArnao can upvote if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix is to add the port to the action attribute of the form.

Change it to

```
action="http://localhost:8080/FirstSpringMVCProject/"
                        ^^^^^
```

However, it would be better to use a [relative url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls). It will be something like:

```
action="/FirstSpringMVCProject/"
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why the port changed... i'll use the relative path to avoid any issues.